# Matlab generates x86 dll but it needs to be x64

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, matlab, dll, matlab-compiler

I have some trouble with my asp.net application which uses matlab functions inside.

I generated matlab function on matlab R2016a and then I generated Dll's via matlab compiler / dotnetbuilder.

At localhost, I build a MVC Web application with VS2013 which takes an integer input and on backend it generates random numbers counts input than matlab function gets the average of these random numbers.

However, it works fine on localhost but it fails on server with Matlab Compiler Runtime 9.0.1 installed. Exception is:
"Unable to load DLL 'mclmcrrt9_0_1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

So I lookup with the dependency walker and I see this;

[focused line is belong to the dll that generated via matlab Library compiler of R2016a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSOZO.png)

It says that matlabs generated dll is in cpu type of x86 even whole application is in x64.

Questions:
1) How can I fix this issue
2) Why this application runs with no exceptions on my own PC

any answers appreciated, if you need any other information just tell me.

Comment: If the application runs on your pc I'd guess either the matlab dll it uses there is 64bit, or your applictaion is 32bit as no other combinations will run? Is the installed matlab runtime 32bit or 64bit (at least in the past those had to be installed seperately)? Does your build command instruct the matlab compiler to build for x64?

Comment: @stijn first of all there is no 32bit version of matlab compiler runtime, so I guess dll's should be for x64 when its compiled. And also I changed my visual studio projects properties of target platform for x64 cpu. afted I changed VS to x64 version it worked on my own PC but on server, it fails.

Comment: Something makes no sense here: 64bit applications cannot load 32bit dlls, ever? You'll likely have to provide more info to get this fixed (minimal sample code, build commands, ...). But first: as far as I know it's not because the CPU column in depends.exe says x86 that the dll is 32bit; from the looks of that screenshot you're loading a 64bit dll into a 32bit depends.exe and that gives funny results. Get 64bit Dependency Walker and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same and have the same problem, Problem didn't solve until I restart the server because of new Environment Variable which defined in windows system after installing Matlab RunTime.
so first restart server.
and be sure that you complied dll with matlab 64bits if use 64bits server.